# Simulator shows Black screen using ionic

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ios-simulator, ionic-framework

i went through ionic sidemenu app when i run emulate ios i get these errors:

```
 Usage of '--family' is deprecated in 3.x. Use --devicetypeid instead.
 Usage of '--retina' is deprecated in 3.x. Use --devicetypeid instead.
 Session could not be started: Error Domain=DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain Code=2 "Simulator          session timed out." UserInfo=0x7f91f97358b0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Simulator session timed
```

and the black screen comes for the simulator

and these are my mac info:
yosemite 10.10
ios-sim version 3.0.0
cordova version 3.6.3-0.2.13
ionic version 1.2.6-beta1
xcode 6.1

Comment: Are you using livereload?

Comment: No I'm not using liverload just i installed latest version of those software through npm but it doesn't work for me only when i open the iOS build of the project with Xcode 6.1 and use the Xcode simulator it works but with the ionic command i faced problem

Comment: What functionality is being provided by ios-sim that you're not able to get from simctl (run 'xcrun simctl help')

Comment: @RaymondCamden have you found a solution to this? I have the exact same problem

Comment: or @sh4hin have you found a solution?

Answer (score 12):

I finally found a solution to fix this problem First setup your application:

1- ionic start myAppname tabs

2- cd myAppname

3- ionic platform add iOS

4- ionic build ios

Then create a file in your projects directory called emulator.sh or whatever name and copy the content of the code below:

```
echo "Emulating..."
cd ./platforms/ios/build/emulator
var=$(pwd)

ios-sim launch "$var"/*.app
```

Set permission for the script: $sudo chmod 777 emulator.sh

whenever you want to emulate your application run the script: ./emulator.sh

so by using this script you don't need to manually open the project in Xcode and run the project

special thanks to Miroslav Masa

Comment: How can I change the emulator from iPhone 4s to something else?

Answer (score 3):

Are you running the ionic command from inside a **tmux** session? tmux seems to be preventing the communication between cordova and the iOS simulator. As soon as I tried running the `ionic/cordova emulate ios` commands directly from the terminal, it worked just fine!

Comment: I'm using both iTerm and Terminal and also reset content and setting in IOS simulator but it still gives me same error

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue and was able to resolve it by:

- Open Xcode
- In the Xcode > Open Developer Tool > iOS Simulator
- iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings
- Restart Mac (uncheck open all windows)

Godspeed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually copy over the latest ionic files into your project after unzipping them as noted here: http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/on-upgrading-to-ionic-beta-13-getting-error-uncaught-referenceerror-interpolate-is-not-defined/10232