# Ionic emulate ios shows black screen

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ios-simulator, ionic-framework

I am playing around with the [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/). Using the default tabs starter project, Ionic is able to both serve (via `ionic serve`) as well as emulate iOS (via `ionic build ios` and `ionic emulate ios`). However, as soon as I start to provide my own implementations, Ionic is not able to emulate the app and shows a black screen. Serving in the browser is still working fine. No errors are displayed.

I have seen [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26014035/simulator-shows-black-screen-using-ionic), but this seems to be a) another problem and b) no working solution is provided. Is anyone experiencing similar problems? I am using *Xcode Version 6.1 (6A1052d)* on *OS X Version 10.9.5* as well as:

```
$ ios-sim --version
3.0.0
$ cordova --version
4.0.0
$ ionic --version
1.2.8
```

Comment: Usually a black screen is due to a problem in the code recently added, modified. Run the app from XCode and open safari and check the console log using the Developer tools. Menu Develop -> iOS simulator. Could you provide a diff between the untouched app and the one with your implementations?

Comment: @fynn found a solution?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delayed answer. I have found that opening the actual Xcode project, cleaning and rebuilding it helps to solve the problem. However, I am not too sure if this is the final solution...

Answer (score 0):

I've been troubling with same problem too and found that the main reason is javascript error. You should check if there is cracked link or javascript fault, and then reset the simulator, clean code run again..

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same black screen when running in iOS but not in web browser. The issue for me was in app.js where the url routing was done, the templateUrl started with a "/folderNameUnderWWW/fileName.tpl.html" after making it "folderNameUnderWWW/fileName.tpl.html" it showed the proper screen on iOS emulator